# 500 response code in HttpURLConnection in android

Tags: android, httpurlconnection

I am having a 500 response code in `HttpURLConnection` in android.I am getting some data from an `api` call.I can't find the issue.I have searched a lot and tried myself but not getting any help.I have code like this in other files and they are running well.There is no error message or exception.
This is my code snippet.

```
private void sendOfferAccepted(String  reqirement_id, final Context contex, String offer_id,String buyer_id, String status) {


        class HttpPost extends
                AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

            String mess = contex.getResources().getString(R.string.server_ip_api);

            String urlString = "https://"+mess+"/api/v1/accept_reject_supplier_offer/";

            private final String TAG = "post json example";

            private Context context;
            private String reqirement_id;
            private Object offer_id;
            private Object status;

            ProgressDialog progDailog = new ProgressDialog(contex);

            public HttpPost(String reqirement_id, final Context contex, String offer_id, String status) {


                this.context = contex;
                this.reqirement_id=reqirement_id;
                this.offer_id=offer_id;
                this.status=status;

            }

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                Log.e(TAG, "1 - RequestVoteTask is about to start...");
                progDailog.setMessage("Loading...");
                progDailog.setIndeterminate(false);
                progDailog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
                progDailog.setCancelable(true);
                progDailog.show();
            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
                String status = "false";

                String response = "";
                Log.e(TAG, "2 - pre Request to response...");

                try {
                    response = performPostCall(urlString, new HashMap<String, String>() {

                        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
                        {
                            put("Accept", "application/json");
                            put("Content-Type", "application/json");
                        }
                    });
                    Log.e(TAG, "4 " + response.toString());
                    if(!response.equals(""))
                    {
                        //Toast.makeText(contex,"response is..."+response,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Log.e(TAG, "3 - give Response111111...");

                    }
                    else {
                        //Toast.makeText(contex,"some error ..."+response,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }


                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // displayLoding(false);

                    Log.e(TAG, "Error ..."+e);
                }
                Log.e(TAG, "5 - after Response...");

                if (!response.equals("")) {
                    try {
                        Log.e(TAG, "6 - response !empty...");
                        //

                        JsonParser jsonParser = new JsonParser();
                        JsonObject jsonobj = (JsonObject) jsonParser.parse(response.toString());

                        status=""+jsonobj.get("message");



                    } catch ( Exception e) {
                        // displayLoding(false);
                        // e.printStackTrace();
                        Log.e(TAG, "Error " + e.getMessage());
                    } finally {

                    }
                } else {
                    Log.e(TAG, "6 - response is empty...");

                    status = "false";
                }

                return status;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                //
                Log.e(TAG, "7 - onPostExecute ..."+result);
                Toast.makeText(context, ""+result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                progDailog.dismiss();


            }

            public String performPostCall(String requestURL,
                                          HashMap<String, String> postDataParams) {

                URL url;
                String response = "";
                try {
                    url = new URL(requestURL);


                    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                    conn.setDoInput(true);
                    conn.setDoOutput(true);

                    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
                    Log.e(TAG,"final url is ..."+url);
                    Log.e(TAG, "11 - url : " + requestURL);

                    JSONObject root = new JSONObject();


                    root.put("requirement_id", reqirement_id);
                    root.put("offer_id", offer_id);
                    root.put("status", status);


                    Log.e(TAG, "12 - root : " + root.toString());

                    String str = root.toString();
                    byte[] outputBytes = str.getBytes("UTF-8");
                    OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
                    os.write(outputBytes);

                    int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
                    Log.e(TAG, "13 - responseCode : " + responseCode);

                    if (responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "14 - HTTP_OK");

                        String line;
                        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                                conn.getInputStream()));
                        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                            Log.e(TAG,"line is "+line);
                            response += line;
                        }
                        Log.e("error is ",response);
                    } else {
                        Log.e(TAG, "14 - False - HTTP_OK");
                        Log.e(TAG,response);
                        //  response = "";
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e(TAG,"exception is ..."+e);
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                Log.e("TAG","response is...."+response);
                return response;
            }
        }

        HttpPost sendPostReqAsyncTask = new HttpPost(reqirement_id,contex, offer_id, status);
        sendPostReqAsyncTask.execute();
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: Try hitting api in Postman.You will get to know about error.

Comment: I already tried postman.API works fine in postman.But in code not.

Comment: 500 is internal server error. if you have access to server logs, you should be able to trace the cause there. If you are getting 500 error code, there  may be some messages added by server to let you know exception cause.

Comment: Recheck the api url and parameters you're using to make the request.

Comment: It cant be the case it will also show 500 in postman.

Comment: I have checked all but I can't find error.I also checked no. of args in postman and code.

Comment: https://httpstatuses.com/500